# Program that compiles and shows Java Swing GUI in real-time

Tags: java, gui, real-time

I want a program that when I copy in a block of [Java Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) code, that will compile the code and show me what the Swing component looks like in real time. Having to continuously run my code to see what the GUI looks like is really annoying.

Comment: I have not heard of swung and can't find it in a web search. Did you mean Swing: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info ? How do you copy the code that is quicker than a command or button to compile and run it? Also which programs have you tried? NetBeans, Eclipse, any plugins?  Explain that and you might attract the attention of someone who has found a solution that meets your needs. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533243/create-gui-using-eclipse-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse

Comment: NetBeans, Eclipse, and other plugins are for creating code. I need to edit code that has been created already, and therefore, those solutions don't really work.

Comment: Yes, I meant swing, edited.

Comment: @ws04 you've missed the swung title :)

Comment: Search for two-way gui development : that way you might find plugins that convert your code to GUI, as well as the other direction. Also, I still don't understand the difference between "compile in real time" and "continuously run". You need to explain clearly what annoys you about the tools you have tried.

Comment: What does continuously run mean? And I haven't tried other tools (except for IntelliJ's GUI form editor and Eclipse's WindowBuilder, but those aren't what I'm looking for.

Comment: [JRebel](http://www.JRebel.com) is a commercial tool added to your IDE that enables hot deployment of code changes to a running app. The purpose is to help the developer by skipping over the full compile-build-run cycle. I doubt it will change an already displayed Swing layout. But if you were to close the layout being modified and re-open it, you would get the new version. I've not used JRebel with Swing (I do [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) work), but it should work. Free trial version available.